# Raid 0 with mixed drives

Tags: raid, raid-1, raid-0, raid-5

I have following 7 physical drives
[image: Physical drives]

When trying to create RAID0
It shows the total capacity as 237.2 instead of 365.2
[image: capacity of mixed discs]

So is there any RAID configuration where I can have a single volume spanning multiple discs of various capacity?

Or am I doing something wrong here

Comment: Your hardware does not support those configurations....but it is possible it's called JBOD

Comment: If you would go RAID0 it would be 7x36.4GB  (using only 36.4GB from the larger disk) for a total of 254.8GB. It is also a very bad idea to stripe thi smany old drives.  Now you could consider three mirrors stiped, or RAID6 or ... and use the larger drive for something else. Or weird combination like twice 3x36GB is stripe and three stripes of that. But I dount that the P400 supports that. You would need software RAID.  And really, with this old hardware pay Eur 100 and replace the drives with one of two newer bigger ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This RAID0 configuration is going to use the maximum amount **common to the individual drives**, in this case 36.4GB, the additional space cannot be included in the volume.